# what is the syntax of INPUT in so file

Tags: symlink, shared-library

When I study the Clang for x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04 Pre-Built Binaries, I see that the libc++.so is not a soft link to the real shared library, it is a text file with text:

```
INPUT(libc++.so.1 -lc++abi)
```

So that -lc++ is just equal to link to libc++.so.1 and then link to libc++abi, I never see such syntax in any of my linux book and can not find any useful reference. I also try to write a libhaha.so with information:

```
INPUT(-la -lb)
```

and see that g++ main.cpp -lhaha is equal to g++ main.cpp -la -lb. It seems that such feature is not just available in clang, it is a general linux feature. I want to know what is the syntax of such feature and whether there is any good reference to talk about such feature. Such feature is very useful, because I can provide a soft link to a group of shared library, not just one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a feature of the GNU linker `ld`. An input file which isn't in a known binary format is tried as a linker script.

Documentation about linker scripts can be found in the ld manual (try `info ld`); I also found [a copy on the web](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html).